# Passing 3D array into MATLAB functions from C# with COM

Tags: c#, matlab, function, multidimensional-array, com

I was trying to pass a 3D array into a MATLAB function from C# with COM. Here's my code:

```
    // here's the code in C#   
    MLApp.MLApp matlab = new MLApp.MLApp();

    //load function
    matlab.Execute(@"cd C:\Users\1303092.local\Matlab\EmGm");

    //initialized input and output
    int[,,] data1 = new int[2,3,5]{{{1,2,3,4,5},{1,2,3,4,5},{1,2,3,4,5}},{{1,2,3,4,5},{1,2,3,4,5},{1,2,3,4,5}}};

    object result1 = null;
    object result2 = null;

    //use function with the data from C#
    matlab.Feval("myfunc", 2, out result1, data1); 

    //type casting
    object[] res1 = result1 as object[];
    double[, ,] data2 = res1[1] as double[, ,];

    //use function with the casted data from MATLAB
    matlab.Feval("myfunc", 2, out result2, data2);

    object[] res2 = result2 as object[];
```

---

```
    // here's the MATLAB function
    function [x,y] = myfunc(a) 
        x = a; 
        y = ones(2,3,5); 
    end
```

I have inserted a breakpoint at the end of the code to check the value in the variables, which is shown as:

### [click here for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Bob3.png)

It seems C# has no difficulty with taking the return values since it did recognise the returned parameter "y". However, there may be some type casting issue when MATLAB takes the array from C#, since the returned parameter "x" was always been recognised as NULL in C#.

I have also tried 2D array in the exactly same way, and everything was running well. Is the error related to the dimensionality here? Any idea guys?

Comment: You do not really have a 3D function  You have : *(x,*y)